# Sencha app build from Intellij Ant build throwing error ruby not detected

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea, extjs, ant, minify

I am trying to run the Build - Production target in my extjs application by importing the sencha build.xml file as the ant configuration file. Most of the targets run except one in slice-impl.xml by giving this error:

```
\application\path\.sencha\app\slice-impl.xml:127: com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: Failed to detect ruby
```

The detailed stack is as follows:

Did not find a system installed ruby runtime
Please install ruby for this platform and ensure that
a ruby command compatible with 1.8 or 1.9 is available
on the system path.

> com.sencha.exceptions.ExNotFound: Failed to detect ruby
>       at com.sencha.command.compass.BaseRubyCommands.runRubyCommand(BaseRubyCommands.java:110)
>       at com.sencha.command.compass.CompassCommands$BaseCompassCommand.execute(CompassCommands.java:123)
>       at com.sencha.command.compass.ant.BaseCompassTask.doExecute(BaseCompassTask.java:99)
>       at com.sencha.ant.BaseAntTask.execute(BaseAntTask.java:34)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
>       at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:217)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor40.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)

ruby installation directory is already part of my System variable Path. What else should be configured to get this work from Intellij?

Comment: yes, the solution was similar. i had added in system variable but was still not working till i restarted idea intellij

Answer (score 0):

This worked after I added ruby path to User Defined variables in addition to system variables and restarted Intellij